PhD supervisors taking too long to correct my thesis
I’m a 4th year PhD student and my scholarship is ending one month from now. I had a meeting with my three supervisors 6 months ago and we agreed together that I would send them each chapter draft as it was completed, over several months, so that there was enough time to make corrections and polish the final version. By July I had sent them 5 chapters (it is now late October) and the only parts I have not yet sent are a chapter that still has results missing (samples sent to another lab, my main supervisor has not updated me on their progress in several weeks) and a synthesis chapter, which is partially written but I would feel more confident about after receiving some feedback from them on the previous parts. So far, they have not sent me any corrections or comments, I have emailed them weekly and reminded them that I have to meet my submission deadline (they have always been aware of when it is) because my scholarship is ending and I am a foreign student. They simply ignore my emails and I feel frustrated, demoralized and I am running out of time to edit and format the thesis (less than 5 weeks until I must submit). Any advice on how to approach the situation without alienating myself from them or seeming entitled?
I will add that in-person meetings with my main supervisor are sometimes worse than communicating via email… she can be quite disorganized and overwhelmed, so when she knows that I’m stressed, she gets quite agitated and dismissive and won’t let me get my concerns across

Since you have 3 supervisors, I wonder whether perhaps each of them is waiting for the others to do most of the correcting and polishing. Or whether perhaps the two non-main supervisors are waiting for the main supervisor, who is too disorganized to get the job done.

You need to go up the chain. Departments don't like it when  students fail just before they are  meant to finish, because their supervisors have other priorities. Can you add a location tag, please?

I don’t quite understand the part about in-person meetings. Is this just general commentary how those meetings usually go, or is it meant to say they are uncomfortable to you and thus you reduce/skip them? Meeting with your supervisor in-person is a natural progression that I would frankly have expected a while ago in your situation, so knowing whether they happen but fail or practically don’t happen makes quite a difference. Note that you can [edit] the question at any time to clarify such points.

I would recommend a face to face meeting between you and each of your supervisors. Maybe everyone together, but individual meetings if that's not possible. In person ideally, but virtually over whatever videoconferencing software you ordinarily use is fine too.
You should plan to lead the meeting. Present what you have done, both research-wise and on the thesis, and lay out a plan for the coming weeks that will get you to a finished submitted thesis. Ask for input to your proposed timeline, but ultimately you need everyone to agree. Ask explicitly about reasons that they have not been able to provide feedback yet: have they not looked at what you've sent so far? Is it so far off their expectations that they don't know where to start? Are they waiting for something else from you or your supervisor?
You should have done this a long time ago, though; by just waiting for things to resolve and doing the same thing over and over for months, you've made your situation much worse. That's at least partly on you, not just your supervisors.
The other person that should be driving this is your primary supervisor. Even if your meetings with them are uncomfortable, you need to be having regular meetings, probably weekly at least. If you haven't been having those for a long time, again, that's at least partly on you. You can't run away from an uncomfortable meeting and expect things to resolve themselves, you have to take on problems head on. Those meetings should involve discussions both of your daily/weekly progress on research as well as your progress towards finishing the thesis. They should include discussions of how to get your other supervisors involved. They should include discussions of what feedback you can expect and why feedback is not coming if it isn't.

Thank you for your suggestion, I agree with you on the necessity of a meeting. Getting them all available at once is tricky due to their schedules (one supervisor is a head of department and another is the rector of the university) and I have suggested several times to have an online meeting, either individually or altogether but they do not respond to those emails either. My main supervisor is easier to pin down schedule-wise, but she can also be evasive when she knows that things are not going to schedule (it’s more her that avoids the uncomfortable encounters than me) but I will keep trying

@RebeccaM Your supervisor may be able to assist you in getting a meeting with the others. Heads of departments are only busy because someone is able to contact them.

You’re right, they generally only respond to things when she (main supervisor) insists with them… However she has been avoiding the issue (I think she might feel some guilt over the missing data perhaps) but I will try harder to motivate her

Are you sure that your emails are reaching the department head and the rector? These people probably have secretaries whose job includes filtering the incoming email.

@AndreasBlass I believe they are, because they respond to other email threads (other topics, meetings for other research that I’m involved in) usually when my main supervisor gets involved or puts pressure on them, they are just silent when it comes to my thesis. I think the main supervisor is key to getting them all moving, but she’s trying to avoid the whole issue because she’s overwhelmed and late on many things

You seem to have two options: let it ride or act on it in spite of "issues".
Weekly emails may have been too much depending on the general workload of your supervisor. They may have been treated as noise, or as updates with no real need to reply. If you need specific help at any point it is good to be specific about what help you need rather than assume they will just "grok" it.
If you are close enough to the end and have other funding of some sort then letting it ride might be rational. More likely though is that you need to go there with a list of specific questions that you need answered. How they react is up to them, of course, but you probably need to make known that you have needs and, most important, what they are specifically.
The big question, of course, is whether you are on track to finish in a timely way and if not what you need to do to fix that. You may be more mature in some ways than your supervisor. Keep that in mind. No real help for that, but it needn't be deadly, provided that you act maturely.

Thanks for your response. To clarify, I haven’t been sending them weekly emails the entire time, at first it was just a polite reminder whenever I sent a new chapter that if they had any corrections on previous parts, they could send them. The weekly emails started earlier this month as I could feel the deadline creeping and wanted to make sure I would have enough time to incorporate changes.

Also some context, in my university system the submitted version of the thesis should be checked and approved by all advisors… and then no changes are made until the defense (which is typically several hours). So more than having specific questions for the advisors, I want to know that they have read and agree with the contents which will be submitted and assessed by the jury

I suggest you ask that specifically of each advisor. Preferably in person. But if you have a meetup, let them know why in advance so you get better than a "snap" answer.

I usually ask my PhD students to send me completed chapters of their thesis or the whole thesis from time to time as they write, but I do not promise an immediate response. It is more important for me to see progress and minimise procrastination. Given that you have not yet finished the thesis, it is a bit premature to claim that they are taking too long to correct it. There could be two obvious reasons for this: either what you are writing is already nearly perfect so they are not worried, or it is so raw and unfinished that they are hoping you will recognise some of the problems yourself and fix them. It would be good for you to understand which of the two extremes is closer to the truth. Your supervisor will not put your thesis high on their priority list until you actually finish it and "submit" (to the supervisors) officially for approval.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
